# NullPointerException From front end angular js to back end spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I 'm working an application using angular js front end and spring boot in back end. I want to affect hotel to user by inserting data into the table usersHotels which is a relation ManyToMany between table gui-user and SystemDefHotel.My problem that when i send data from the front to back i get: error 500() NullPointerException which means the back end has received null value from front end

this is my class UsersHotels:

```
public class UsersHotels implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long id;
private User user;
private SystemDefHotel hotel;
// additional fields
private boolean linked;

public UsersHotels() {
    super();
}

public UsersHotels(long id, User user, SystemDefHotel hotel, boolean linked) {
    this.id = id;
    this.user = user;
    this.hotel = hotel;
    this.linked = linked;
}

public UsersHotels(User user, SystemDefHotel hotel) {
    super();
    this.user = user;
    this.hotel = hotel;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_Hotel_ID")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOTEL_CODE")
public SystemDefHotel getHotel() {
    return hotel;
}

public void setHotel(SystemDefHotel hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel;
}
public boolean isLinked() {
    return linked;
}

public void setLinked(boolean linked) {
    this.linked = linked;
}
```

My function service.java to affect Hotel to user:

```
@Override
public void affectHotelToUser(UsersHotels userhotel) {  

        SystemDefHotel hotel= hotelDao.findHotelByName1(userhotel.getHotel().getHotelName());

        userhotel.setHotel(hotel);
        User user= dao.findById(userhotel.getUser().getUserId());
        userhotel.setUser(user);
        dao.saveUserHotel(userhotel);

}
```

My controller.java:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/affectHotelToUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Void> affectHotelToUser(@RequestBody UsersHotels userHotel ) {
    SystemDefHotel us=userHotel.getHotel();
    User h=userHotel.getUser();
    UsersHotels uh= new  UsersHotels(h, us);
    usersService.affectHotelToUser(uh);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

In the front angular js :this is my service.js:

```
service.affectHotelUser = function(userHotel){
    console.log("User: ", userHotel.User );
    console.log("SystemDefHotel: ", userHotel.hotel );
    return $http.post(_contextPath + '/affectHotelToUser', userHotel).then(
            function(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function(errResponse) {
                console.log("user Hotel error 1: ", userHotel.hotel );
                console.log("user Hotel error 2: ", userHotel.User );
                console.error('Error while sending data');
                return $q.reject(errResponse);
            });
};
```

the controller.js:

```
$scope.nameHotelSelected={};    
     $scope.affectHotelUser = function(){
     console.log("newUser : ",$scope.newUser);
     var userHotel={
            User:$scope.newUser,                
            linked:true,
            hotel: $scope.nameHotelSelected

             };

     console.log("userId : ",$scope.newUser.userId);
     console.log("hotelCode : ",$scope.nameHotelSelected.code);     
      UsersService.affectHotelUser(userHotel).then( function(d) {
          $scope.users  = d
          console.log("userscwvcb",   $scope.users);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while adding userHotel');
        });
    };
```

and my view:

```
<table class="detailsHotelLink"  cellspacing="1" >
            <tr  >
                <td align="right" style="height: 35%;width: 10.5%"  >Add new link        :</td>
                <td style="width: 500%;"  >
                <select  type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="nameHotelSelected"   placeholder="contact" ng-options="nameHotel.name for nameHotel in hotels" ng-change="changedValue(this)" >
<option value="">Select Account</option>
            </select>               
            </td>                   
            </tr>
            <tr >               
              <td align="right"  style="height: 32%"> Hotel   :  </td>
              <td><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addHotelUser" >{{nameHotelSelected.name}}</a> 
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"  ng-click="deleteHotel()"></i> 
              <div class="modal fade" id="addHotelUser" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="true" >
                    <div class="modal-dialog"> 
     <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h5 class="">Edit Link</h5>
                  </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-group" >                  
                  <div class="group text-center">   
                <input type="text" ng-model="nameHotelSelected.name"  required>                         
                 </div>               
                </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">     
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-green" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>      
                    <button type="button"  id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="affectHotelUser()" >Save</button>         
         </div>
</div>      


</td>
```

this is my stacktrace:

```
janv. 03, 2018 10:40:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/neorchaWEBPlatform] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lbc.takeoff.neorcha.business.service.UsersServiceImpl.affectHotelToUser(UsersServiceImpl.java:385)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.affectHotelToUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.lbc.takeoff.neorcha.web.controller.UsersController.affectHotelToUser(UsersController.java:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.lbc.takeoff.neorcha.web.configuration.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I 'm sorry for this question but really i still don't find the solution. any help thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your stacktrace, please

Comment: @Patrick thanks for your response ,i added the stacktrace .

Comment: can you also show us the part of `UsersServiceImpl.java:385`

Comment: this ligne in the service.java: "userhotel.setUser(user);" because in this method public void affectHotelToUser(UsersHotels userhotel)  gets null value of the userhotel".